# activating a variable named file

Tags: vba, excel

```
   Windows(mNummer & "_" & Jahr & "_" & Welle & ".xlsm").Activate
```

So here is my code;  mNummer,Jahr,Welle are variables and xlsm is the file type as you all know. I get an error when i want to activate this file. What is the reason for this ?

Comment: **1)** Is the file open? **2)** If so, try `Workbooks(mNummer & "_" & Jahr & "_" & Welle & ".xlsm").Activate` **3)** Even better try `Set wb = Workbooks(mNummer & "_" & Jahr & "_" & Welle & ".xlsm")` and work directly with the `wb` object (Dim wb as Workbook). **4)** Lastly, double-check that the string you build indeed produces a valid Workbook name according to your files.

Comment: You might want to check in the direct window of the VBE what you're looking for: `?Windows(1).Caption`.

Comment: ? automatically converted to print and i got an error saying it is not allowed to use it

Comment: Are you sure the variable name creates the correct string? Test this by making a String variable, making it equal to your formula, and then print it so you can see what it looks like [this is also what @Ralph was recommending, using the VB Editor window].

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change `Windows` to `Workbooks`